# SSL and Non-Secure Resources

Tags: php, security, ssl

I know there have been questions regarding an https:// webpage, and people who have gotten warnings and the "red" padlock on their browser.

I am having the same issue, however, I *know* what the culprit is.

On part of my website, I allow content (basically a news feed and picture via RSS) to be displayed to the user.  The resources are trusted, but just not secured. My issue is:  the content that's being delivered is not coming from a secure location, nor does it have the capability.  (For example, I tried accessing one of the articles by adding an "https", but no go.)

I know that one method is to not allow the RSS feed to be delivered.  But is there any way around this?  Is there any way to take a non-secure feed and make it secure before delivering it to my end-user?

I just don't want the annoying "red" padlock to keep showing up.

Any help on this would be great.  I am using primarily PHP and jQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: Any security indication should not be considered as annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you load resources from non-SSL urls into an SSL page, you will get the security warnings. There is no way around it other than proxying the insecure content so it goes to the client through your server over an SSL-protected link.

Comment: I would add that proxying insecure content through your own server is also taking a certain "responsibility". To an extent, that's vouching for the content you serve (and may cause problems regarding bypassing same-origin policies).